# Is a female dog licking her vulva always a sign of a problem? Or can it be just pleasure masturbation (not an issue)?

Tags: dogs, behavior

I think my dog is sometimes masturbating by licking her vagina very passionately while making humping motions while she is in heat. Can a dog actually do this for pleasure to themselves (i.e. there is nothing wrong)?

All the threads I found said there may be a problem, but none of them mentioned that it can be merely an act of pleasure and no problem.

Is it possible it is merely a pleasurable act, not some vaginitis or whatever?

Comment: Animals do not have this kind of erogenous areas as humans have. For most pets like cats (I remember a likewise question about cats... searching for it) and dogs mating is not a pleasure also. I am not a dog expert, but if it is some kind of masturbation, than I can imagine only some kind of need comparable with scratching an itchy spot. In each case you should visit or call a vet for advice, if you are in concern about the health of your pet. Instead of waiting for strangers from the internet ;)

Comment: Found it, and it is also about dogs: [Would sterilizing a male/female cat/dog ruin their sex-life?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/26785/would-sterilizing-a-male-female-cat-dog-ruin-their-sex-life/26794#26794)